# Python's random.randint() function appears to hang after a few hundred iterations in a for loop?

Tags: python, random

I have the following Python function in Jupyter Notebook:

```
def remove_random(df, group_counts):
    df = df.copy()
    blanks = set()
    if isinstance(group_counts, list):
        for groups, count in group_counts:
            for _, row in df.iterrows():
                current = 0
                while current < groups:
                    start = random.randint(0, len(row) - count)
                    cut = {x for x in range(start, start + count)}
                    if not cut.issubset(blanks):
                        current += 1
                        for i in range(start, start + count):
                            row[i] = np.nan
                            blanks.add(i)
    else:
        groups = group_counts[0]
        count = group_counts[1]
        
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            i = 0
            print(_)
            while i < groups:
                start = random.randint(0, len(row) - count)
                cut = {x for x in range(start, start + count)}
                if not cut.issubset(blanks):
                    for i in range(start, start + count):
                        row[i] = np.nan
                        blanks.add(i)
                    i += 1
    return df
```

It is a function which removes n groups of j random points from a list; however, the indices being removed may not repeat and have to be unique each iteration. `df` is a pandas DataFrame, and `group_counts` is either a tuple or a list of tuples of the format (n, j).

When printing the row index as in the code above, the console shows that the rows of `df` are processed up to around 400 give or take a few, and when I kill the notebook it usually traces the point of execution to `random.randint()`, though I have seen it land on the `issubset()` as well. I have tried reseeding the random number generator but that did not fix the issue. Other than that I cannot find any bugs in my code which would be causing this problem. Moreover, as far I can tell from the output speed, the function chugs along quickly until stalling on row 400 so I don't think that using `issubset()` is causing a slowdown.

Comment: I mean, it *sounds* like your function is fundamentally polynomial time or something, and you are reaching the point where it starts to slow down significantly. `random.randint` doesn't just hang after a few hundred iterations.

Comment: But why would it progress quickly and then just suddenly stop moving altogether? Like it takes less than 1 second between iterations from the print statements and then around 400 it halts completely, doesn't even move if I leave it for 5 minutes. That seems like an unreasonably large time gradient to be attributed to complexity.

Comment: No, not really. Sounds like classic exponential growth. Also, `print`ing and your own judgement are not a good way to tell anything like that. You should actually try to time each iteration if you really want to get any handle of growth characteristics of the function.

Comment: Quite frankly, you jhaven't provided a [mcve] but the other culprit is the fact that your while-loop only teminates probabilitically. Are you sure you aren't entering some state where `i` will never be less than `groups`? Or it suddenly becomes very improbably (coupled with the growing complexity of `issubset`. Again, this is **definitely** not due to `random.randint` suddenly hanging after a couple hundred iterations. You can pretty much assume that is not the case.

Comment: Looking at `while i < groups:`. Inside that is `for i in range(start, start + count):` which reassigns `i`. There is nothing explicit in the code that would make that while ever stop. Did you want a different indexing variable in that inner `for`?

Comment: @tdelaney changing `for i in range(start, start + count):` to using `j` instead changes the output, now it appears to only cycle through 13 rows each time before stopping.

Comment: `if not cut.issubset(blanks):` - if this isn't true, you don't get `i += 1` and are still stuck in the `while`. Not sure why you didn't bump into that at first, but just looking at the code, you still have a potentially infinite while loop.